Do we have a FAQ for why backups are desirable?
Every day (in the year 2024), about 385,000 people are born. At some point in their future, they will need to know that they need to make backups of their data.
Many of them may turn to Super User when their data is in peril.
Is there an exemplary Q&A where the reasons for making backups, and how many backups to make, is made clear?
I looked in community-faq but either my eyesight is growing weak or it isn't there.

The comments on this question in the past few days say that there isn't - but if I were to make a Q&A for it, would it be likely to be closed as seeking opinion?
Would it be a useful Q&A? My idea was that instead of writing "you should have had a backup blah blah blah too much for a comment", we could link to some "how backups can save you" Q&A.

There's this, but it addresses the "what do I do?" rather than the "why?":
How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?

Unfortunately most will only be searching out that information when it's too late. It's an education problem that should ideally be solved at the school level. You would hope it's part of the curriculum that their IT teachers are teaching them, but I have my doubts that most of those teachers are competent enough to run regular backups.

@JoepvanSteen This one? Yes, cringe.
